# Android WebView zoom in to match div width

Tags: android, html, webview, zooming

I need to display HTML formatted text in my Android app. I get HTML from the server. It looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 9em; background-color: #00FF00;">
    <img src="smiley.png" />
    <pre>abc  123  456  789</pre>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I put this in WebView I get the following result (image):

http://s11.postimg.org/gu3a6ybpf/Screenshot_2014_09_12_17_08_25.png

But I need to zoom in the WebView, so that the "div" (the green square) will match the screen from left to right. This is the result I am looking for (image):

http://s4.postimg.org/554ayxqot/Screenshot_2014_09_12_17_14_14.png

The result must look the same on all screen sizes (phones, tablets, ...) and all orientations (portrait, landscape).

I have tried everything and checked plenty of forums, but didn't found the solution to my problem. Can somebody please tell me how to get the result I want.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried style="width=100%; height:100%"?

Comment: I need the width of the div to be exactly 9em wide. If I put width: 100%; then the green square will be full screen.